# How to implement np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view efficiently in JAX?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba, jax

I have implemented an algorithm in which I calculate the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between a vector in one image and every vector in another image within a given window around the equivalent pixel. In pure numpy, I am implementing this with [np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view):

```
import numpy as np

def pcc(img1, img2, m, n):
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]
    img1_mean = img1.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    _img2_mean = _img2.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    img1_img1_mean = img1 - img1_mean
    _img2__img2_mean = _img2 - _img2_mean
    img1_img1_mean_swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        img1_img1_mean, (_m, _n), axis=(-2, -1)
    )
    numerator = (img1_img1_mean_swv * _img2__img2_mean[..., None, None]).sum(axis=-5)
    denominator = np.sqrt(
        (img1_img1_mean_swv * img1_img1_mean_swv).sum(axis=-5)
        * (_img2__img2_mean * _img2__img2_mean).sum(axis=-3)[..., None, None]
    )
    return numerator / denominator
```

One of the main problems with this implementation is that some of the intermediate arrays are very large ~40Gb with image shapes of `10, 2048, 2048` and `m=n=5`. I would like to implement a JAX equivalent, but I am struggling to reimplement `sliding_window_view` efficiently. This is my JAX implementation of `sliding_window_view` for a 2d window shape over the last two axes of an array inspired by the discussions [here](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/3171), [here](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/11354) and [here](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/14188):

```
from functools import partial
from jax import config
config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def _moving_window2d(matrix, window_shape):
    matrix_width = matrix.shape[-1]
    matrix_height = matrix.shape[-2]

    window_width = window_shape[0]
    window_height = window_shape[1]

    startsx = jnp.arange(matrix_width - window_width + 1)
    startsy = jnp.arange(matrix_height - window_height + 1)
    starts_xy = jnp.dstack(jnp.meshgrid(startsx, startsy)).reshape(
        -1, 2
    )  # cartesian product => [[x,y], [x,y], ...]

    def _slice_window(start):
        return jax.lax.dynamic_slice(
            matrix, (start[1], start[0]), (window_height, window_width)
        )

    return jax.vmap(_slice_window)(starts_xy).reshape(
        matrix_height - window_height + 1,
        matrix_width - window_width + 1,
        window_height,
        window_width,
    )

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def moving_window2d(matrix, window_shape):
    func = _moving_window2d
    for i in range(matrix.ndim - 2):
        func = jax.vmap(func, in_axes=(i, (None, None)), out_axes=i)
    return func(matrix, window_shape)
```

The jax version of `pcc` is then:

```
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(2, 3))
def pcc_jax(img1, img2, m, n):
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]
    img1_mean = img1.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    _img2_mean = _img2.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    img1_img1_mean = img1 - img1_mean
    _img2__img2_mean = _img2 - _img2_mean
    img1_img1_mean_swv = moving_window2d(img1_img1_mean, (_n, _m))
    numerator = (img1_img1_mean_swv * _img2__img2_mean[..., None, None]).sum(axis=-5)
    denominator = jnp.sqrt(
        (img1_img1_mean_swv * img1_img1_mean_swv).sum(axis=-5)
        * (_img2__img2_mean * _img2__img2_mean).sum(axis=-3)[..., None, None]
    )
    return numerator / denominator
```

I've also tried, passing a sliding window view as an argument to the function instead (which ideally I don't want to do, just for comparison):

```
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(2, 3))
def _pcc_jax2(img1_swv, img2, m, n):
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]
    img1_swv_mean = img1_swv.mean(axis=-5, keepdims=True)
    _img2_mean = _img2.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    img1_swv_img1_swv_mean = img1_swv - img1_swv_mean
    _img2__img2_mean = _img2 - _img2_mean
    numerator = (img1_swv_img1_swv_mean * _img2__img2_mean[..., None, None]).sum(axis=-5)
    denominator = jnp.sqrt(
        (img1_swv_img1_swv_mean * img1_swv_img1_swv_mean).sum(axis=-5)
        * (_img2__img2_mean * _img2__img2_mean).sum(axis=-3)[..., None, None]
    )
    return numerator / denominator

def pcc_jax2(img1, img2, m, n):
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    img1_swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        img1, (_m, _n), axis=(-2, -1)
    )
    return _pcc_jax2(img1_swv, img2, m, n)
```

Whilst these implementations do result in a faster computation than the pure numpy code, they don't compare to my numba implementation (for the 3D case - I only really care about 3D & 4D):

```
import numba as nb

def _pcc_numba(img1, img2, m, n):
    assert img1.shape == img2.shape
    assert img1.ndim == 3
    K, M, N = img1.shape
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]

    img1_img1_mean = img1.copy()
    _img2__img2_mean = _img2.copy()
    
    _K = float(K)

    for i in nb.prange(M):
        for j in range(N):
            _mean1 = 0.0
            for k in range(K):
                _mean1 += img1[k, i, j]
            _mean1 /= _K
            for k in range(K):
                img1_img1_mean[k, i, j] -= _mean1

    img1_img1_mean_swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        img1_img1_mean, (_m, _n), axis=(-2, -1)
    )

    out = np.empty((M - _m + 1, N - _n + 1, _m, _n), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in nb.prange(M - _m + 1):
        for j in range(N - _n + 1):
            _img2__img2_meanij = _img2__img2_mean[:, i, j]

            _mean2 = 0.0
            for k in range(K):
                _mean2 += _img2[k, i, j]
            _mean2 /= _K

            denominator2 = 0.0

            for k in range(K):
                _img2__img2_meanij[k] -= _mean2
                denominator2 += _img2__img2_meanij[k] * _img2__img2_meanij[k]

            for a in range(_m):
                for b in range(_n):
                    numerator = 0.0
                    denominator = 0.0
                    for k in range(K):
                        numerator += (
                            img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b] * _img2__img2_meanij[k]
                        )
                        denominator += (
                            img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b]
                            * img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b]
                        )
                    out[i, j, a, b] = numerator / np.sqrt(denominator * denominator2)
    return out

pcc_numba = nb.njit(fastmath=True)(_pcc_numba)
pcc_numba_parallel = nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)(_pcc_numba)
```

Test and time:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
shape = (10, 400, 400)
img1 = rng.random(shape)
img2 = rng.random(shape)

out = pcc(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_numba = pcc_numba(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_numba_parallel = pcc_numba_parallel(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_jax = pcc_jax(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_jax2 = pcc_jax2(img1, img2, 5, 5)

assert np.allclose(out, out_numba)
assert np.allclose(out, out_numba_parallel)
assert np.allclose(out, out_jax)
assert np.allclose(out, out_jax2)

%timeit pcc(img1, img2, 5, 5)
%timeit pcc_numba(img1, img2, 5, 5)
%timeit pcc_numba_parallel(img1, img2, 5, 5)
%timeit pcc_jax(img1, img2, 5, 5).block_until_ready()
%timeit pcc_jax2(img1, img2, 5, 5).block_until_ready()
```

Results:

```
804 ms ± 7.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
81.7 ms ± 539 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
19.2 ms ± 77.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
417 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
639 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Therefore, my question is how do I perform a sliding window view like operation efficiently in JAX?

Whilst the question is primarily aimed at JAX, I am open to any improvements to my numpy or numba code.

Answer (score -2):

try this out:

```py
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import partial
import numba as nb

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def _moving_window2d(matrix, window_shape):
    matrix_height, matrix_width = matrix.shape[-2], matrix.shape[-1]
    window_height, window_width = window_shape[0], window_shape[1]
    starts_x = jnp.arange(matrix_width - window_width + 1)
    starts_y = jnp.arange(matrix_height - window_height + 1)
    starts_xy = np.moveaxis(np.meshgrid(starts_x, starts_y), 0, -1).reshape(-1, 2)
    
    def _slice_window(start):
        return matrix[..., start[1]:start[1] + window_height, start[0]:start[0] + window_width]

    return jax.vmap(_slice_window)(starts_xy)

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(2, 3))
def pcc_jax(img1, img2, m, n):
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]
    img1_mean = img1.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    _img2_mean = _img2.mean(axis=-3, keepdims=True)
    img1_img1_mean = img1 - img1_mean
    _img2__img2_mean = _img2 - _img2_mean
    img1_img1_mean_swv = _moving_window2d(img1_img1_mean, (_n, _m))
    numerator = (img1_img1_mean_swv * _img2__img2_mean[..., None, None]).sum(axis=-5)
    denominator = jnp.sqrt(
        (img1_img1_mean_swv * img1_img1_mean_swv).sum(axis=-5)
        * (_img2__img2_mean * _img2__img2_mean).sum(axis=-3)[..., None, None]
    )
    return numerator / denominator

def _pcc_numba(img1, img2, m, n):
    assert img1.shape == img2.shape
    assert img1.ndim == 3
    K, M, N = img1.shape
    _n = 2 * n + 1
    _m = 2 * m + 1
    _img2 = img2[..., m:-m, n:-n]

    img1_img1_mean = img1
    
    _K = float(K)

    for i in nb.prange(M):
        for j in range(N):
            _mean1 = 0.0
            for k in range(K):
                _mean1 += img1[k, i, j]
            _mean1 /= _K
            for k in range(K):
                img1_img1_mean[k, i, j] -= _mean1

    img1_img1_mean_swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(
        img1_img1_mean, (_m, _n), axis=(-2, -1)
    )

    out = np.empty((M - _m + 1, N - _n + 1, _m, _n), dtype=np.float64)

    for i in nb.prange(M - _m + 1):
        for j in range(N - _n + 1):
            _img2__img2_meanij = _img2__img2_mean[:, i, j]

            _mean2 = 0.0
            for k in range(K):
                _mean2 += _img2[k, i, j]
            _mean2 /= _K

            denominator2 = 0.0

            for k in range(K):
                _img2__img2_meanij[k] -= _mean2
                denominator2 += _img2__img2_meanij[k] * _img2__img2_meanij[k]

            for a in range(_m):
                for b in range(_n):
                    numerator = 0.0
                    denominator = 0.0
                    for k in range(K):
                        numerator += (
                            img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b] * _img2__img2_meanij[k]
                        )
                        denominator += (
                            img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b]
                            * img1_img1_mean_swv[k, i, j, a, b]
                        )
                    out[i, j, a, b] = numerator / np.sqrt(denominator * denominator2)
    return out

pcc_numba = nb.njit(fastmath=True)(_pcc_numba)
pcc_numba_parallel = nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)(_pcc_numba)

rng = np.random.default_rng()
shape = (10, 400, 400)
img1 = rng.random(shape)
img2 = rng.random(shape)

out_jax = pcc_jax(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_numba = pcc_numba(img1, img2, 5, 5)
out_numba_parallel = pcc_numba_parallel(img1, img2, 5, 5)

assert np.allclose(out_jax, out_numba)
assert np.allclose(out_jax, out_numba_parallel)

%timeit pcc_jax(img1, img2, 5, 5).block_until_ready()
%timeit pcc_numba(img1, img2, 5, 5)
%timeit pcc_numba_parallel(img1, img2, 5, 5)
```

Comment: it doesn't work? TracerArrayConversionError on the line `starts_xy = np.moveaxis(np.meshgrid(starts_x, starts_y), 0, -1).reshape(-1, 2)` and converting them to use `jax.numpy` just gives another error because you're trying to do `moveaxis` on a list of arrays not on an array